# Unable to parse bindings, Url is not defined;

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I m learning and new to Knockout. I m trying to use `Ko.Computed` to return image url, my images are stored in

***Images*** folder on root.

. On loading page I got below error:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>
> Message: ReferenceError: Url is
>
> not defined;  Bindings value: text:Url

My code is given below:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            // Model
            var Model = {
                id: "1",
                path: "/Images/"
                
            };

            // ViewModel
            var ViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.Id = ko.observable(Model.id);
                self.path = ko.observable(Model.path);
                self.Url = ko.computed(function () {
                    return self.path+ self.Id+".jpg";
                });
                // etc...
            };

            ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);



        }); 
    </script>
```

My HTML markup is:

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src:Url}" />
<span data-bind="text:Url"></span>

<span>Photo Id:</span>
<input data-bind="value:Id" type="text" />
```

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);` should be `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());`

Comment: @haim770 thanks, sorry to ask but can u please guide when I should use new and when without new, as I m new to Knowckout. Thanks

Comment: `applyBindings` is expecting an `object` that contains the data to bind. your `ViewModel` variable is referencing a `function`, you need to create an instance of `ViewModel` using the `new` operator. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
self.Url = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.path() + self.Id() + ".jpg";
});
```

Because `path` and `Id` are observables, you should call them to get value

**EDIT:** You also should create object before applying bindings as @haim770 suggested

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: @karaxuna, thanks. I tried this it do not displayed image but error is gone. Can you please guide why path and Id should be used as path() and Id() yet they are properties.

2. Can you please give any tip how I can debug it, as in mark up there is no error and also it just shows binding text. Please guide

Comment: @user576510 1. observables are functions, so you should call them to get value. You can log for example `console.log(self.path)` and you'll see it's a function. 2. If you want to debug, do it this way: `var path = self.path()` in computed function and see what value holds `path` variable. You can debug js in chrome developer tools for example